# UI Buttons only partially clickable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

[image]

I made a custom view `Xib` file with 2 buttons and I call it in my view controller but when I press the buttons the bottom part is not clickable only when I press the top part as in the image .. how can I resolve it?

```
//this class of Xib file 
class AddCart: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var cartImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnYes: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnNo: UIButton!
var view:UIView!
var index = 0
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setup()
}

func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.roundedCorners()
    btnNo.roundedCorners()
    btnYes.roundedCorners()
    //make rounded image and add border to it


    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]; addSubview(view)
}
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "AddCart", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}

override func willRemoveSubview(subview: UIView) {
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}
}

//here where i call it 
if(addCart != nil && !addCart.view.hidden)
        {
            addCart.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        addCart = AddCart(frame: CGRect(x:((width)/2)-((600)/2), y:((height)/2)-(133/2), width:600, height:133))
        addCart.btnYes.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProductContentVC.addToCart(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        addCart.btnNo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProductContentVC.addToCart(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        addCart.btnYes.backgroundColor = appColor
        addCart.btnNo.backgroundColor = appColor
        self.addView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.width, height:self.height)
        self.addCart.frame = CGRect(x:(self.width/2)-((self.width - 10)/2), y:(self.height/2)-((133)/2), width:(self.width - 10), height:(133))
        self.view.addSubview(addView)
        self.addCart.alpha = 1
        self.addView.addSubview(self.addCart)
```

Comment: Show your code, and view Hierarchy

Comment: Try to set `clipsToBounds = true` on the xib, to check if the xib is smaller than the actual button

Comment: Please share code so we can help you out

Comment: Just give background color to view and check that that buttons are in view or not

Comment: Check your view is inside its superview, this is the most common reason

Comment: @Rajat See in question "he will click top but not bottom" So its fine that view is in superview

Comment: @Jecky, this is also possible that the view is going outside its superview from the bottom, that's why it is not responding to user's touches

Comment: @Rajat But he load XIB  into superview so I think its not possible

Comment: @Jecky - check the links in this google search, in most of the cases this issue is due to frame of superview - https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=UIbutton+not+clickable+xcode&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PEZaWKOoDaTT8gf2-ZaQCg

Comment: @Rajat yeah, but there is no question for button from loading xib

Comment: please provide code of your XIB and code where you are adding it into your view controller

Comment: i did put my code wish it will be helpful

Comment: 'addCart.clipsToBounds = true' 
when I added this code i found most of buttons outside their super view but i don't understand why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was the problem in the height of the custom view ..it was 172 height but in code i gave it height 133 thats why buttons was outside the super view ..but i changed it in the code to 172 my problem resolved alhamdulillah